# Link Document Library to Search Filter

Tags: web-part, filter, content-search-web-part, refiner

I have a SharePoint Content site which also has a document library. The document library has columns that classify the document.  I am trying to (on the homepage of the content site) add a Search Refiners Web Part that will filter the different columns of the document library and show results.

I have:
1.) Found my crawled properties for the columns, they showed up as ows_Column1, ows_Column2, etc and mapped them to Managed Properties. I named the MPs as Column1MP etc.
2.) When I create the refiner, the created MPs show up on the dropdown selection.
3.) I set up a search result webpart and connect it to the refiner webpart, but have no idea as to why nothing is showing up. I have selected several options and nothing is happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the SharePoint version?

Comment: @KapilDave I am working with SharePoint Online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit "search result webpart" > click "Change query".

In "Query text" type path to your list/library

```
Path:"https://.../Lists/testList/" (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)
```

Check if your Managed Properties are (Query Retrieve Refine Sort Safe) like OOTB refinable managed properties.

Comment: It worked, but when I have no filters applied it shows documents from other SharePoint sites. How do I remove that?

Comment: Did you set correct path in Query text > Path:"https://YOURSITE/YOURSUBSITE/Lists/testList/" . When you set path to your library, search result will get only that library. In Query text you only need path to your library and (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)